# browsing ruby on rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, conventions

Is there a way to find out what methods are defined in the rails' classes ? I think the rails' api is not really easy to browse at all. Do I have to memorise every thing mentioned in unstructured explanations like very essential one `ActionController::Base`. I don't even know is there a method other than `params`, which I had to memorise. I know ruby emphasise convention over configuration but so many implicit methods , rules , conventions are quite challenging. Any advice for me to get used to it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using this website? - http://api.rubyonrails.org/

All of the methods on each class are documented and easily searchable.

For example, search for `Application` and you'll find the main rails application class, which inherits from `Engine`.

Within that you can see all of the methods directly defined by that class. For inherited methods you can simply click the parent class.

Methods defined on `Application` are:

```
allow_concurrency?
call
env_config
inherited
initialized?
key_generator
load_rack_cache
new
reload_routes!
show_exceptions_app
```